# how can i make the alarm start in the specific date in the future ?

Tags: android

how can i make the alarm  start in the specific date in the future ?

the code below should start alarm every month in a specific day .

what happen is that the alarm start immediately and not in the given date also it is repeated next month in the day that started at and not in the given day.

for exemple :

i set day = 15 , month = 3 , year = 2014.

Today is 10 / 2 /2014.

i start the alarm today and it's strat immadiatly;

then next month it's start at 10/3/2014 and not at 15/3/2014.

can u help me plz...

```
            Calendar calendar3 = Calendar.getInstance();

            calendar3.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH , day);
            calendar3.add(Calendar.MONTH , month);
            calendar3.add(Calendar.YEAR , year);

            Intent intent3 = new Intent(context, RepeatedTransaction.class);
            intent3.putExtra("transType" , transType);
            intent3.putExtra("transid" , transid);

            PendingIntent pendingIntent3 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, transRepeatedId + 2, intent3, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            AlarmManager am3 = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            am3.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, desireHour, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * calendar3.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), pendingIntent3);
```

Comment: What is `desireHour`? Given that it has "hour" I'd assume something less than 24; which means it should happen (almost) immediately. The second param is `time in milliseconds that the alarm should first go off`
[method doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating(int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent))